# Как вшить БД в мобильное приложение?

Tags: android, база-данных, c++builder

Интересна такая вещь. Есть БД MS Access и программа на смартфонах и ПК.Приложение кросс-платформенное и на C++ Builder. Если же я скомпилирую apk или exe, то мне данные из БД не будут доступны? Можно как-то вшить в программу, чтобы бд вместе с ней поставлялась?

IOS

[image: IOS]

[image: Android]

[image: Windows]

[image: BeforeConnection]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

БД Access под Android работать не будет. Поэтому, если хотите поставлять БД вместе с программой под Android, используйте SQLite в связке с FireDAC.
Как это сделать по шагам описано в [документации Embarcadero](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE7/en/Mobile_Tutorial:_Using_FireDAC_in_Mobile_Applications_%28iOS_and_Android%29).

Comment: Не получилось у меня, если честно. Выскакивает ошибка, что не найдена таблица Employee

Comment: Что конкретно не получилось? Перенести БД в SQLite или включить БД в программу? Опишите подробно, что и как Вы делаете. Чтобы можно было если не сразу подсказать что не так, то хотя бы воспроизвести ошибку. Варианты из серии: "у меня не получилось" здесь не прокатывают.

Comment: Не получилось включить БД в программу. Я сейчас еще раз хочу попробовать, но только со своей БД. Я делал все, что было указано в инструкции, добавил нужные компоненты, соединил BindingSource с ListView, файл в Deployment указал и путь на смартфонах, но кажется одного не учел - нужно было еще и в Connection компоненты поменять на каждом устройстве.

Comment: Есть ещё один момент. В C++ Builder, как и в Delphi, пути к локальным БД лучше прописывать программно с учётом платформы.

Comment: Есть какой-нибудь материал по такому подключению? Я не понимаю какой путь прописывать, мой на компьютере или путь на смартфонах и других компьютерах?

Comment: Еще добавил к вопросу скрины с Deploymenta. Сделал как в туториале, + Код добавил для BeforeConnection у FDConnection